# Group of order 15 acting on a set of order 22

Tags: abstract-algebra

If a group of order 15 acts on a set of order 22 and there are no fixed points. How many orbits are there?

I know the group action corresponds to a homomorphism from G into $S_{22}$

Comment: WHatare the possible sizes of the stabilizers?

Comment: Well stabilizer is a subgroup of G right so 1,3,5 or 15, but if it was 15 then we would have a fixed point which we don't. So 1,3, or 5.

Comment: Ok, so what are the possible sizes of the orbits, then?

Comment: 15,5 or 3 so must be 4 orbits of order 3 and 2 of order 5?

Comment: @user9352 Looks good to me!

Comment: Indeed. You have just answered your own question. You should write in more detail what you did in the answer box.

Answer (score 1):

Mariano's comment is the key point, but maybe you need more of a push. Let's call the group $G$ and the set $S$.

$S_{22}$ is a pretty large group, so my mind wouldn't jump there. Rather, the orbits of the action partition $S$, and if $s \in S$ then the size of the orbit $Gs$ containing $s$ is the index $(G : G_s)$ of the [stabilizer subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem) of $s$. Using [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) and the fact that $G$ has no fixed points (What restriction does this place on the order of $G_s$?) we get three possibilities for the index.

Now this becomes a familiar problem: how many ways can you make $22$ using addition and these three numbers? There should be only one.

Comment: In the last sentence I mean "up to reordering".